# How to use | symbol in windows command prompt

Tags: windows

Am trying to generate key hash using this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

but cannot create the `|` symbol in windows.Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: shift + \ doesn't do it? what is the language/internationalization specs for your keyboard? for instance mine is US 105+

Comment: Depends on your keyboard layout, naturally. Still, there’s no trick to it.

Comment: Last resort, you could copy/paste it.

Comment: You can use the on-screen keyboard built in with Windows, or look at your physical keyboard, look for the `|` sign and Shift + Press that key..., or copy/paste. Which laptop/keyboard do you have

Comment: Wow,thanks. shift + \ works.I was busy trying ctrl + \ and ctrl+ alt + \

Comment: Yeah, @FrankThomas add your comment as an answer.

Comment: I see no problem with this question. Why the downvote?

Comment: -1 so your keyboard had a | on it above \ and you saw that and you couldn't figure out that that uses shift

Comment: @barlop I'm not the OP :) And, it's a simple error - the keyboard doesn't say 'Use Shift, not Ctrl'...

Comment: @barlop +100 for being a smartass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On US and most western keyboards, the pipe character is the Shift character for the backslash key, so try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>